# looping through method for insert in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynccallback

There are three things that I need to insert

1. country
2. state
3. city

`async.waterfall` method has `insertCountry`

The `insertcountry` contains the following logic:

```
var listofCountry = "source file to read the list of country" //a file is there from where i read the countries
listofCountry.forEach(function(objCountry) {
  createCountry(data, next) //with some logic i have my data object already filled.
  createState() //in this method i need to pass the countryId that i have just created.
}, this);

//this is the method that will carry insert of country, **Request data** is a generic method and works fine.

function createCountry(data, next) {

  Request(data, {
      api: "myApi",

      uri: "/Country/create",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        "name": "data.CountryName",
      }
    },
    function(error, response) {
      if (response && response.data !== undefined && response.data !== null) {
        data.countryId = response.data.CountryId; // the debugger is not coming here.hence not setting the countryId
      } else if (response && response.error !== undefined && response.error !== null) {
        error = response.error;
      }
    });
}
```

I feel there is some incorrect implementation of `async` or `callback`, I'm not sure.

Comment: can you please post the full async code?

Comment: you aren't showing us the waterfall part + you never call next in your createCountry